# How can I configure JAX-RS endpoints programmaticaly?

Tags: apache, jax-rs, osgi, cxf, osgi-bundle

I'm trying to get rid of XML in my project.
I already tried to add this:

```
JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
sf.setResourceClasses(CustomerService.class);
sf.setAddress("http://localhost:9000/");
sf.create();
```

to my Activator class, but my bundle wont start with this.

So, how usually people configuring endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry, no code, just some high level insights from my experience/projects)

I use jersey and its integration into the OSGi environment. I.e. `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer` to which I register all jax-rs resources. This way, I can use whatever HTTP server implementation is available (for example, jetty) and configure it via the OSGi system environment properties.

For simplicity, I re-register annotated OSGi (declarative) services as singleton resources/endpoints into that ServletContainer.

Maybe, CXF has also a similar approach.